# How to apply multiple imports in XSLT for xml generation

Tags: xml, xslt

My xml only picks the last import(IdentifierXSLT) and not the above ones; and i want to import all the others.Can i use apply Template in all xslts that are needed to be imported?
 How can i achieve that? Any help would be appreciated.

My XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:import href="DocumentHeaderXSLT.xsl"/>
            <xsl:import href="IdentifierXSLT.xsl"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:element name="ApplicationBatch">
                <xsl:namespace name="xsi" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'"/>
                <xsl:namespace name="xsd" select="'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'"/>
                <xsl:apply-imports/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

My Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApplicationBatch xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <DocumentHeader>
      <SchemaName xsi:type="xsd:string">AcmeCorp_MotorApplicationRequest</SchemaName>
      <SchemaVersion xsi:type="xsd:string">v1_0</SchemaVersion>
   </DocumentHeader>
   <Identifier Type="LenderAssigned" UniqueID="ACMECORP"/>
   <Submission>
      <Date>2017-03-07</Date>
      <Time>09: 07: 39.1373551+11: 00</Time>
   </Submission>
</ApplicationBatch>
```

DocumentHeaderXSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="DocumentHeader">
            <xsl:element name="SchemaName" >
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">xsd:string</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ApplicationBatch/DocumentHeader/SchemaName"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:element name="SchemaVersion">
                <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type">xsd:string</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="/ApplicationBatch/DocumentHeader/SchemaVersion"/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IdentifierXSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Identifier">
            <xsl:attribute name="Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="/ApplicationBatch/Identifier/@Type"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="UniqueID">
                <xsl:value-of select="/ApplicationBatch/Identifier/@UniqueID"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output:

```
<ApplicationBatch ProductionData="Yes"
                  xmlns:xsd="htt://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <DocumentHeader>
        <SchemaName xsi:type="xsd:string">AcmeCorp_MotorApplicationRequest</SchemaName>
        <SchemaVersion xsi:type="xsd:string">v1_0</SchemaVersion>
    </DocumentHeader>
    <Identifier Type="BrokerAssigned"
                UniqueID="Ref24723"/>
</ApplicationBatch>
```

My output:

```
<ApplicationBatch ProductionData="Yes"
                  xmlns:xsd="htt://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Identifier Type="BrokerAssigned"
                UniqueID="Ref24723"/>
</ApplicationBatch>
```

Comment: XSLT uses all the xsl:import declarations. If your code isn't doing what you think it should, then you need to supply evidence.

Comment: Thank u Michael. But i don't understand how to supply evidence?

Comment: Give us complete input so that we can reproduce the problem (removing anything that's irrelevant), including details of what processor you were running, and tell us your expected output and your actual output.

Comment: Micheal i have given that details.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `xsl:apply-templates`, all the matching template rules are considered, and the one with highest *import precedence* wins. If you want more than one template rule to be executed for the same node, there are various options: you can call apply-templates twice in different *modes*, or you could have one template rule invoke the other using `xsl:apply-imports` or `xsl:next-match`.

Comment: Thanks Michael. This really helped me out.

Comment: Sorry @OleV.V. i am new to this ; i had up voted the answer. I will mark it now.

Comment: NP. It takes some time to learn to use this site. I’m trying to help others learn and enjoy when someone else helps me…